# Maven dependencies for jjwt (json web token) on a spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jwt, jjwt

Which maven dependency in my pom.xml should I add to resolve these errors:
-SignatureException cannot be resolved to a type
-ExpiredJwtException cannot be resolved to a type
-UnsupportedJwtException cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Can you please add more details in question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding these dependencies on my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Instead of using jjwt-api and jjwt-impl both you can use jjwt only.

Comment: E.g: 
```<artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>```